# PHP Short arrays based on sub-object value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array where contains simple objects. The array I have looks like the following:

```
[posts] => Array
    (
        [0] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 4
                [post_title] => Post #4
                ...
             )
        [1] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 100
                [post_title] => Post #100
                ...
             )
        [2] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [post_title] => Post #1
                ...
             )
        [3] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 21
                [post_title] => Post #21
                ...
             )
    )
```

also I have an array that contains the first array posts ID in the order I like to show that posts. Lets say that the array map likes like that:

```
[map] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 21
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 1
    )
```

Now the quation. Can I order the array that contains the objects, based on each object ID Property by using as a map the Map array, in order to have a result that will look like this:

```
[posts] => Array
    (
        [0] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 4
                [post_title] => Post #4
                ...
             )
        [1] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 21
                [post_title] => Post #21
                ...
             )
        [2] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 100
                [post_title] => Post #100
                ...
             )
        [3] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [post_title] => Post #1
                ...
             )
    )
```

Comment: Check the sorting functions that provide a callback, see if that helps http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Where does the array come from originally? I would start right there and see whether it would not be easily possible to modify that code so that it uses the post id as array key in the first place.

Comment: This is the array produced by the WordPress when using the WP_Query. If you run a WP_Query and print_r the result you will find the array I am using above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a builtin way to do this, using the [`array_multisort`](http://us.php.net/array_multisort) function:

```
$col = array();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $col[] = array_search($post->ID, $map);
}

array_multisort($col, $posts);

// now $posts is sorted in the order specified in $map
```

Try it here: http://codepad.org/5rqncj3B

Answer (score 1):

My solution maybe isn't efficient, but it's simple:

```
function find_post_by_id($posts, $id) {
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    if ($post->id == $id) {
      return $post;
    }
  }
  // error handling here
}

$sorted_posts = array();
foreach($map as $id) {
  $sorted_posts[] = find_post_by_id($posts, $id);
}
```